# Проблемы с кастомизацией InfoWindowAdapter

Tags: android

Всем привет! переопределяю InfoWindowAdapter. Если я в макете ставлю картинку, то нормально отображает картинку. А если в коде, то выдаёт java.lang.NullPointerException.

```
TextView titleTextView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.titleTextView);
titleTextView.setText(marker.getTitle());
ImageView ratingImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ratingImageView);
ratingImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.big00);
```

В чём проблема? ругается на эту строку:  
        ratingImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.big00);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ratingImageView);
```

наверное должно быть

```
(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.ratingImageView);
```

Comment: спасибо, невнимательность)